# wcscat_s function - buffer error

Tags: c++, windows, string, pointers, concatenation

The question is simple: what's frong with this piece of code?

```
  size_t  buff = 1;
  size_t  new_buff;
  WCHAR   *var_path;
  WCHAR   *dir_path;

  var_path = new WCHAR[buff];
  new_buff = GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"APPDATA", var_path, buff);

  if (new_buff == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else if (new_buff > buff) {
    delete[] var_path;

    var_path = new WCHAR[new_buff];
    GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"APPDATA", var_path, new_buff);
  }

  dir_path = new WCHAR[new_buff];
  wcscpy_s(dir_path, new_buff, var_path);
  wcscat_s(dir_path, new_buff, L"\\directory");
```

It says that the Buffer is too small on `wcscat_s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only allocate `new_buff` characters for `dir_path` (and tell `wcscat_s` about that size), then you want to append more characters to it. You need to allocate `new_buff` **plus** the length of `L"\\directory"`, as well as tell `wcscat_s` about that actual size.

Comment: It was the solution, and it was so simple! Thank you.